# Java Pool actions3d (remake libGDX actions) how to make a copy of action3d

Tags: java, object, libgdx, copy

I have problem with making a NEW of object.

Example classes that I'm using:

```
public class Actions3d{

/** Returns a new or pooled action of the specified type. */
static public <T extends Action3d> T action3d(Class<T> type)  {
    Pool<T> pool = Pools.get(type);
    T action = pool.obtain();               
    action.setPool(pool);
    return action;
}

static public AddAction addAction(Action3d action) {
    AddAction addAction = action3d(AddAction.class);
    addAction.setAction(action);
    return addAction;
}

static public RemoveAction removeAction(Action3d action) {
    RemoveAction removeAction = action3d(RemoveAction.class);
    removeAction.setAction(action);
    return removeAction;
}
...
}
```

Here is example of one specific Action3d

```
abstract public class Action3d implements Poolable {
/** The actor this action is attached to, or null if it is not attached. */
protected Actor3d actor3d;

private Pool<Action3d> pool;

/**
 * Updates the action based on time. Typically this is called each frame by
 * {@link Actor#act(float)}.
 * 
 * @param delta
 *            Time in seconds since the last frame.
 * @return true if the action is done. This method may continue to be called
 *         after the action is done.
 */
abstract public boolean act(float delta);

/** Sets the state of the action so it can be run again. */
public void restart() {
}

/** @return null if the action is not attached to an actor. */
public Actor3d getActor3d() {
    return actor3d;
}

/**
 * Sets the actor this action will be used for. This is called automatically
 * when an action is added to an actor. This is also called with null when
 * an action is removed from an actor. When set to null, if the action has a
 * {@link #setPool(Pool) pool} then the action is {@link Pool#free(Object)
 * returned} to the pool (which calls {@link #reset()}) and the pool is set
 * to null. If the action does not have a pool, {@link #reset()} is not
 * called.
 * <p>
 * This method is not typically a good place for a subclass to query the
 * actor's state because the action may not be executed for some time, eg it
 * may be {@link DelayAction delayed}. The actor's state is best queried in
 * the first call to {@link #act(float)}. For a {@link TemporalAction}, use
 * TemporalAction#begin().
 */
public void setActor3d(Actor3d actor3d) {
    this.actor3d = actor3d;
    if (actor3d == null) {
        if (pool != null) {
            pool.free(this);
            pool = null;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Resets the optional state of this action to as if it were newly created,
 * allowing the action to be pooled and reused. State required to be set for
 * every usage of this action or computed during the action does not need to
 * be reset.
 * <p>
 * The default implementation calls {@link #restart()}.
 * <p>
 * If a subclass has optional state, it must override this method, call
 * super, and reset the optional state.
 */
public void reset() {
    restart();
}

public Pool<Action3d> getPool() {
    return pool;
}

/**
 * Sets the pool that the action will be returned to when removed from the
 * actor.
 * 
 * @param pool
 *            May be null.
 * @see #setActor3d(Actor)
 */
public void setPool(Pool pool) {
    this.pool = pool;
}

public String toString() {
    String name = getClass().getName();
    int dotIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (dotIndex != -1)
        name = name.substring(dotIndex + 1);
    if (name.endsWith("Action"))
        name = name.substring(0, name.length() - 6);
    return name;
}   

}
```

Example of specific Action3d

```
public class VisibleAction extends Action3d {
private boolean visible;

@Override
public boolean act(float delta) {
    actor3d.setVisible(visible);
    return true;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}
}
```

Adding combination of Actions to one action.

```
Action3d action = Actions3d.sequence(
                Actions3d.moveTo(-20, 0, 0, 5),
                Actions3d.moveTo(-20, 0, -20, 5),
                Actions3d.moveTo(0, 0, -20, 5),
                Actions3d.moveTo(0, 0, 0, 5)
        );
```

Or how to make a Actions3d.sequence(..) returns a new object?

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: I would create a method that creates and returns the sequence action, and then you can call it as many times as you like to get copies of the same thing. This would probably perform better and be less error prone than doing some sort of deep copy with reflection.

Comment: I would like to implement there something like that: `protected PooledEntity newObject () {
    return new PooledEntity();
}` but it don't working could you help me with implementation?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If this Actions3d API is anything like libgdx's scene2d, then `Actions3d.sequence(...)` is creating a new object.

Comment: It does not make a new object... That is what I need to make there.

Comment: Can you show your `sequence` method so we can see what's wrong with it?