# LibGDX pool do not create a new object

Tags: java, libgdx

How to make an Actions3d.sequence(..) return a new object?

I need to make a action:

```
Action3d action = Actions3d.sequence(
                            Actions3d.moveTo(-20, 0, 0, 5),
                            Actions3d.moveTo(-20, 0, -20, 5),
                            Actions3d.moveTo(0, 0, -20, 5),
                            Actions3d.moveTo(0, 0, 0, 5)
                        );
```

and this action set to many actors.

First actor works but when I add next one the first one stops move and second starts from beginning position and he is two time quicker.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Pool actions3d (remake libGDX actions) how to make a copy of action3d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233685/java-pool-actions3d-remake-libgdx-actions-how-to-make-a-copy-of-action3d)

Comment: Editing your existing question bumps it, so there's no need to create a new one. In both cases, we can't help you if you don't show us your `sequence` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
public Action3d getAction(){
        SequenceAction action = new SequenceAction();

        for(Vector3 pos : playerStation.getPath()){
            action.addAction(Actions3d.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, 5));
        }
        return action;
    }
```